# Programmatically List Custom Type Count for Log Analytics per Custom Log

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics

In Azure Log Analytics, you can only have 500 custom fields per custom log.

I want a way to programmatically monitor which of my custom logs in a workspace is nearing that limit, or already at that limit.

How can I find this information using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the Azure CLI to get this information.  It's not the most performant method, but at least it's a start.

```
az cloud set --name AzureUSGovernment
# Login using your OMS creds (AAD)
az login
az account set --subscription 2000000d-4000-000f-a000-00000000000f
$resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup"
$workspaceName = "myWorkspaceName"
$WORKSPACE_ID = "d0000000-6000-4000-8000-000000000002"
```

I logged in to the Azure Government AAD where my LA workspace was located, and set some variables to work with.

```
$schema = az monitor log-analytics workspace get-schema -g $resourceGroupName -n $workspaceName | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I retrieved all of the custom fields for the entire workspace, by requesting the workspace schema.  Alternatively, I could have simply requested the custom logs (tables), but the CLI and API commands I was using was returning HTTP 500 errors (more on that later).

```
$customTables = $schema.value.ownerType | Select-Object -Unique | Where-Object { $_ -match "_CL" }
```

I gathered a list of custom logs by filtering down to tables that ended in "CL".  To be fair, this only works for custom logs that are using at least one custom field, but in my use case that was fine.

```
$customTables | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$(((az monitor log-analytics query -w $WORKSPACE_ID --analytics-query "$_ | getschema | summarize count()" -o json -t PT1M) | ConvertFrom-Json).count_) | $_" }
```

For each custom log, I ran a Log Analytics query `myTable_CL | getschema | summarize count()` to get a count of custom fields used by that table.  You could tweak this query to get other information if you needed to, since you could use this method to run a query against every custom table / custom log you have.  The above command prints out counts for each table in the collection.

---

I mentioned before that you could get custom logs in a cleaner way, but for me at this time I was getting errors for the two methods below:

```
# Retrieves workspace table list, can return resource provider error, even though Microsoft.OperationalInsights is registered.
az monitor log-analytics workspace table list --resource-group "myResourceGroup" --workspace-name "myWorkspaceName"
```

The above was complaining about a resource provider missing, even though I had the proper ones registered.  It also complained about API version, which I wasn't sure how to override in the request.  I was running Azure CLI 2.32.0.

```
# Retrieves workspace table list, can return HTTP 500 error for no reason.
az rest --method get --url "https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/$workspaceName/tables?api-version=2020-08-01"
```

The above method simply returned "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error".  Not sure why, so I had to go with using the entire workspace schema instead.

Comment: Helpful ISO 8601 reference for specifying time span in AZ CLI LA queries (`-t`):
https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm